# How do I handle workspace in Jenkins plugin for Pipeline & Freestyle?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Was just taking a look at https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/DEVGUIDE.md.

I originally had this:

```
public boolean perform(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener) {
  // The Jenkins job's workspace
  FilePath path = new FilePath(build.getWorkspace(), "bpsSpec.yml");
  // ...
}
```

After reading the upgrade guide I changed it to

```
public boolean perform(Run<?,?> build, Launcher launcher, TaskListener listener) {
  FilePath workspace = null;
  // The Jenkins job's workspace
  if (build instanceof AbstractBuild) {
    workspace = build.getWorkspace();
  }

  FilePath path = new FilePath(workspace, "bpsSpec.yml");
  // ..
}
```

The docs say `Use the specified workspace rather than the former build.getWorkspace()`... but I'm not sure who is specifying that and how. Also `build.getWorkspace()` is causing a compilation error, probably because I've never used *generics* before and am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement [SimpleBuildStep's overload of perform](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/tasks/SimpleBuildStep.html#perform-hudson.model.Run-hudson.FilePath-hudson.Launcher-hudson.model.TaskListener-) instead, and it receives a directory as argument.

Comment: Thanks. Worked great. Just added the import `implements SimpleBuildStep`, and made the function header change on `perform`.